# Get huge number of tweets by location

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, machine-learning, twitterapi-python

I want to get all tweets for a specific topic that tweeted from NYC. I have twitter credential and my Python code to use the Twitter API is the following:

```
import tweepy

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("......", ".......")

auth.set_access_token("........", "........")


api = tweepy.API(auth)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Tweets', 'Date of Tweet', 'Retweet Count', 'User Location', 'User Registration Date'])



def stream():

    i = 0

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='climatechange', count=100000, lang='en', tweet_mode='extended', since='2020-02-2', until='2020-02-25',geocode='43.17305,-77.62479,100km').items():

        print(i, end='\r')

        df.loc[i, 'Tweets'] = tweet.full_text

        df.loc[i, 'Date of Tweet'] = tweet.created_at

        df.loc[i, 'Retweet Count'] = tweet.retweet_count

        df.loc[i, 'User Location'] = tweet.user.location

        df.loc[i, 'User Registration Date'] = tweet.user.created_at       

        df.to_csv('GeoTweets1.csv')

        i+=1

        if i == 10000:

            break

        else:

            pass

stream()



df.info()
```

Questions:
1- I want to get metadata. I mean big data of tweets as much as I can. we know that every 15 min we can request 180 keywords and by each request, we can get 100 tweets, which means 18000 tweets. How can I iterate the code that it gives me 18K tweets for a specific keyword and automatically repeat it every 15min? For example, to get tweets of NYC about climatechange, I want to continuously run this code for 10hrs, which equals to 40 of 15mins, which means I can get 720K tweets.

2- I also have the issue to get tweets according to location. When I run the above code and request tweets for a keyword such as climatechanges, it gives me 100 tweets, but for Geo query for New York gives me less. e.g. for geocode='43.17305,-77.62479,32km it gives me 22 tweets and for geocode='43.17305,-77.62479,100km  it gives me 12 tweets. Why for Geo search it doesn't give me 100 tweets
Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, very few Tweets (around 1% of total Tweets) have precise geolocation added by the user, so this is completely expected. There is no way to force Twitter users to add their location to their Tweets. Geolocated searches will likely limited your results as you described.

Comment: how can I use a loop to request data many times and append it to the csv file?